# TailwindCSS Flexbox Navbar Links Not Displayed Inline

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am still learning both TailwindCSS and flexbox, but despite following instructions on building a navbar, I'm not getting the desired outcome. Instead of having my links displayed as inline-block, they are stacked vertically. Is there something that I am missing from my class codes for the links I'm trying to display as inline block? Or does it have to do with the class attributed inherited by the flexbox attributes I provided the parent div?

Here is the outcome:

[image: outcome]

```
<header class="container">
    <nav class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between px-6 lg:px-16 bg-indigo-100">
        <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 text-white">
            <a class="#" href="{{@site.url}}">
                {{#if @site.logo}}
                    <img src="{{@site.logo}}" alt="{{@site.title}}" class="w-50 h-50" />
                {{else}}
                    {{@site.title}}
                {{/if}}
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Menu Button (Mobile) -->
        <div class="block lg:hidden">
            <button class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-teal-200 border-teal-400 hover:text-white hover:border-white">
            <p>Menu</p>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="inline-block">
            {{navigation}}
        </div>
        <div class="inline-block">
            {{#if @site.facebook}}
            <a href="{{facebook_url @site.facebook}}" title="Facebook" target="_blank" rel="noopener">{{> "icons/facebook"}}</a>
            {{/if}}
            {{#if @site.twitter}}
            <a href="{{twitter_url @site.twitter}}" title="Twitter" target="_blank" rel="noopener">{{> "icons/twitter"}}</a>
            {{/if}}
            <a href="https://feedly.com/i/subscription/feed/{{@site.url}}/rss/" title="RSS" target="_blank" rel="noopener">{{> "icons/rss"}}</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Here is the {{navigation}} portion:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-home nav-current"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-about"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TailWindCSS](http://tailwindcss.com) is utility first CSS framework. Check below HTML.

```
<header class="container">
    <nav class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between px-6 lg:px-16 bg-indigo-100">
        <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 text-white">
            <a class="#" href="{{@site.url}}">
                {{#if @site.logo}}
                    <img src="{{@site.logo}}" alt="{{@site.title}}" class="w-50 h-50" />
                {{else}}
                    {{@site.title}}
                {{/if}}
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Menu Button (Mobile) -->
        <div class="block lg:hidden">
            <button class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-teal-200 border-teal-400 hover:text-white hover:border-white">
            <p>Menu</p>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="inline-block">
            <ul class="nav flex flex-row">
    <li class="nav-home nav-current"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-about"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
</ul>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-row">
            {{#if @site.facebook}}
            <a href="{{facebook_url @site.facebook}}" title="Facebook" target="_blank" rel="noopener">{{> "icons/facebook"}}</a>
            {{/if}}
            {{#if @site.twitter}}
            <a href="{{twitter_url @site.twitter}}" title="Twitter" target="_blank" rel="noopener">{{> "icons/twitter"}}</a>
            {{/if}}
            <a href="https://feedly.com/i/subscription/feed/{{@site.url}}/rss/" title="RSS" target="_blank" rel="noopener">{{> "icons/rss"}}</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

[Flexbox Complete Guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Here is navbar [demo](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/eYmRJjG) using TailwindCSS.